# Parsing a URL using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the 'Meghan' part from the line:

```
link = http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Meghan.html
```

...with the following regex:

```
print re.findall('by_(\S+).html$',link)
```

I am getting the output:

```
[u'Meghan']
```

Why I am getting the 'u'?

Answer (score 0):

It means unicode. Depending on what you'll do with it, you can ignore it for the most part, of you can convert it to ascii by doing `.encode('ascii')`

Comment: If this helped you, please upvote and/or the answer. :)